# Recursive c++ function

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function as follows.

The function takes a counter `k` and as long that the counter is larger than zero I would like to call it recursively so that in the end I end up with something like this:

```
result = 2(2(2n+1)+1)+1
```

where the last n (when k=0) should be zero.

```
int pass(int k, int n)
{
    if(k==0)
    {
        n = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        k--;
        return pass(k, 2*n+1);
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a hint as on how to do it?

Comment: You need a base case on that recursion. if k==0 you should return 0, not just set n.

Comment: If `k==0`, the function returns with no `return` statement.   That causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have changed to return 0;, but It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
n = 0;
```

To

```
return n;
```

To return the result.

The rest of the code is fine

Answer (score 2):

Currently the behaviour of your code is *undefined* since you don't explicitly return a value on all control paths.

Your code can simplify down to:

```
int pass(int k, int n)
{
    return k ? 2 * pass(k - 1, n) + 1 : 1;
}
```

Here I've used the *ternary conditional operator*. `2 * pass(k - 1, n) + 1` is returned if `k` is non-zero, 1 is returned otherwise.

Take care not to overflow your `int` in this case. Note that the maximum size of an `int` can be as small as 32767. Consider using a `long` type instead.

Also, note that recursion is not normally a good way of solving O(n) type problems; you could get errors at runtime due to a function call stack limit being exceeded: consider folding to a loop instead.

Comment: While this is simple to me, you and other programmers, it might not be more simple (readable) to someone not yet familiar with ternary op.

Comment: I was just about to submit a solution using templates ;-)

Comment: @TimBeaudet then it is time to get familiar with the ternary op. I am more puzzled by the simplification of the formula...

Comment: I think I'm wrong. Oops. The resulting term is a function of n.